# AS3 - setTextFormat(), defaultTextFormat not working as designed?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

UPDATED with simpler snippet

I am building a Flash swf to check through some XML files using AS3.

I only have access to the Flex compiler, not the actual Flash IDE or Flashdevelop, so all my xml checking code is a single AS file, compiled into an swf. In order to display information, I create and add a TextField and call appendText() (I use += in this snippet).

The snippet below seems to not set the new format on existing text. It appears to not have any effect whatsoever on the text.

I was under the impression that setTextFormat would change the existing text and that any new text added after calling setTextFormat would use the defaultTextFormat object. This does not appear to be the case in my code. Am I incorrect in my understanding?

```
public function AS3Tester()
{
    display_txt = new TextField();
    display_txt.multiline = true;
    display_txt.width = 1024;
    display_txt.height = 768;

    var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    tf.size = 12;
    tf.font = "Lucida Console";

    display_txt.defaultTextFormat = tf;
    display_txt.text = "Text Before setTextFormat\n"; //Should use default style tf
    addChild(display_txt);

    var tf2:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    tf2.size = 18;
    tf2.color = 0xFF0000;

    display_txt.setTextFormat(tf2);

    display_txt.text += "Text after setTextFormat\n"; //previous line should use tf2, this new line should use default tf

}
```

Comment: `defaultTextFormat` is just that, the default it will use if nothing else is explicitly set. However, if you set the `.text` property first then add a `defaultTextFormat`, I don't think it will change anything until the next time you update the .text property.   `setTextFormat` only sets the format for the specified text (by default everything), if you append text after a setTextFormat, it's no longer a part of what was there before and you'd need to do `setTextFormat` again.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I wonder if appending text and using += somehow is the problem? And for that matter, are style sheet objects the preferred approach to formatting text now?